# Mailchimp block/table padding

Tags: outlook, html-email, mailchimp

I am trying to customise a mailchimp drag and drop template by nesting some basic css in the pre-header which works perfectly except for one customisation.

I am wanting boxed text, and any other item with a coloured background to stack flush without any padding - as in, I don't want any white between or around the blocks.

This is what I have tried for text boxes:

```
.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer td {
    padding:0 !important;
}
.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent {
    padding:18px 18px 16px 18px !important;
}
```

Which removes it from the outer and adds it to the inner.

This works like a charm but in Outlook (ofcourse) it doesn't sit right.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

An entirely custom html is out of the question as the client need to be able to use the drag and drop builder which correct if I am wrong, is unavailable in any form for custom emails.

Also - if anyone knows how to remove the horizontal borders (the grey ones in the image) in outlook that would be great - which appear even without any form of customisation from me.

[image: outlook]

Answer (score 0):

> An entirely custom html is out of the question as the client need to
>   be able to use the drag and drop builder which correct if I am wrong,
>   is unavailable in any form for custom emails.

That's incorrect, [you can code custom emails for MailChimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/) while still allowing clients to edit, duplicate, delete, and reposition content.

If you can, try putting this directly on the table near the problem area:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I do that, the whole button dissappears

Comment: Don't delete the entire button just add cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;" to the table tag

Comment: Hey Mia - I actually ended up looking at a custom builder after your initial comment which I am very happy with. I was told that you could not use the Mailchimp builder for custom emails, not realising you could have a custom email with building options for clients. Thanks for your help